# Call Function inside of return of another function

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I'm using React Native and I need to call function test() inside the return of function mapObject in my render(), whats is the best way to do that? Now I'm getting teste() is not a function.

You can see the code here:

```
mapObject(object_, callback) {
    if(object_)
    {
        return object_.map(function (key) {
            return callback(key);
        });
    }
}

test(v1, v2){
    var t = v1-v2
    return t
}

render() {
    return (
        <View>
        {this.mapObject(this.state.JSONreturn, function (key, value) {
          return (
          <Text>{key.number1}  / {this.test(key.number1, key.number2)</Text>
          )
        })}
        </View>
    )
}
```

Comment: how are you calling the test function? "this.test()" isn't working?

Comment: Have you bound `test` in your constructor?? if no, try this `this.test = this.test.bind(this);`

Comment: @Rodius Yes and getting this.test is not a function.

Comment: @EsirKings Yes I tried and not working.

Answer (score 0):

since you are trying to call it from a map function, you need either use a arrow function or pass 'this' as a second argumment of your function:

```
return object_.map(function (key) {
            return this.callback(key);
        }, this);
```

or:

```
return object_.map((key) => {
            return callback(key);
        });
```

Comment: try keep the result of the function inside a variable and then return it.